# Do different databases use different name quote?

Tags: mysql, database

For example, mysql quote table name using

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`;
```

notice the `

Does other database ever use different char to quote their table name

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This use of quotes is called delimited identifiers.  It's an important part of SQL because otherwise you can't use identifiers (e.g. table names and column names) that:

- Include whitespace:  "my table"
- Include special characters and punctuation: "my-table"
- Include international characters: "私のテーブル"
- Are case-sensitive: "MyTable"
- Match SQL keywords: "table"

The standard SQL language uses double-quotes for delimited identifiers:

```
SELECT * FROM "my table";
```

MySQL uses back-quotes by default.  MySQL can use standard double-quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM `my table`;
SET SQL_MODE=ANSI_QUOTES;
SELECT * FROM "my table";
```

Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase uses brackets by default.  They can both use standard double-quotes this way:

```
SELECT * FROM [my table];
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
SELECT * FROM "my table";
```

InterBase and Firebird need to set the SQL dialect to 3 to support delimited identifiers.

Most other brands of database use double-quotes correctly.

Comment: I'm trying to format the back-ticks according to the markdown syntax but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing.  It appears correct in the preview but after I save the edit, it reverts to showing the backslashes and putting the word in monospace font.  Alas.

Comment: I have reformatted the answer to put back-quotes into code blocks.

Comment: To use backticks within a code block: put in the beginning and the end of the block a double backtick `` and in your code block a single backtick `

Comment: In my SQL Server both `[ ]` and `" "` work. Is this also expected?

Comment: @fedorqui, I would conclude that you or someone else configured `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER=ON` or else that it's now on by default on SQL Server.

Comment: Yes! I later on discovered this... and also that you can even name a table `Table]` and then query it with `... FROM [Table]]] ...`. Very weird things. It's very kind of you to enlighten [again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15005909/1983854), Bill!

Answer (score 3):

Succinctly, yes.

The SQL standard uses double quotes around the name to indicate a 'delimited identifier'.

Informix by default uses single and double quotes interchangeably to indicate character strings.  However, by setting the environment variable DELIMIDENT you can turn on the SQL standard behaviour - single quotes around strings and double quotes around delimited identifiers.

Other people have listed other behaviours for other DBMS; I don't need to repeat those.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server uses [square brackets] or "double quotes" when QUOTED_IDENTIFIER option is ON.

I believe double quotes are in the SQL-92 standard.