# Preventing escaping apostrophes with parameter query not working

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am trying to prevent from having to escape apostrophes in my string variables by using a parameterized query with a SqlConnection, but it is not working. any help would be appreciated.

UPDATED: this is current code...

```
 'Populate Connection Object
 Dim oCnn As New SqlConnection(strConnection)

 'Define our sql query
 Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO [" & foreignTable & "] (data_text) VALUES (@data_text) ; "

 'Populate Command Object
  Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, oCnn)

  'Add up the parameter, associated it with its value

   oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_text", data_text)

  'Opening Connection for our DB operation  
  oCnn.Open()

  Try
      Dim results As Integer = oCmd.ExecuteScalar
  Catch ex As Exception
      LabelImport.Text &= "<font color=red>ROOT Import ERROR: " & ex.ToString & ", From Database: " & dbName & ", Text String: " & data_text & "</font><br />"
      Throw
  End Try

  oCnn.Close()
  oCmd.Parameters.Clear()
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's not right.

It should look like this:

```
Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO [" & foreignTable & "] (data_text) VALUES (@data_text);"
```

and for the parameter:

```
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_text", data_text)
```

Note: I don't "think" you can pass the table name as a parameter.  You would have to have the table name in the string.  See [Parametise table name in .Net/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/372033/719186)

Also, change this:

```
Dim results As Integer = oCmd.ExecuteScalar
```

to

```
Dim results as Integer = oCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: ITs working now except for the 10 records or so with apostrphes

Comment: @marc11h Can you define not working for the 10 records with apostrophes?  Errors?

Comment: Yes given the number can be much larger, this is test data.

Comment: I think I got it. The issue is that the record is not getting inserted. No reported error.

Comment: @marc11h Maybe edit your question by adding the new code you are using now.  It's pretty straight forward how this works, so I'm guessing you still have a syntax error.

Comment: NOPE, the records with apostrophes are still not getting INSERTED.

Comment: @marc11h Updated answer.  You should be using `ExecuteNonQuery`.  `ExecuteScalar` is for return one column, one record "Select" statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use table name only when creating query (I mean concatenating it from parts: `"INSERT INTO " + foreignTable + " (data_text) VALUES...`, AFAIK), not as query parameter. Check [SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue.aspx) for more information about `SqlCommand` parameters, there is very good example as well.

```
'Populate Connection Object 
Dim oCnn As New SqlConnection(strConnection) 

'Define our sql query 
Dim sSQL As String = "INSERT INTO " & foreignTable & " (data_text) VALUES (@data_text);" 

'Populate Command Object 
Dim oCmd As New SqlCommand(sSQL, oCnn) 

'Add up the parameter, associated it with its value 
oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_text", data_text) 

'Opening Connection for our DB operation   
oCnn.Open()
```

**Edit:**

`+` changed to `&` because of C# as "native language".