# How to edit and update a GridView whose headers are not static and unknown

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

A table is created in the database with a **customer** name (which is entered in a `TextBox`). The fields of the table created are the items in the `ListBox`. Like:

```
com = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE " + Label6.Text + " (Locations nvarchar(20), " + ListBox3.Items[0].ToString().Trim() + " nvarchar(5))", con);
con.Open();
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();

for (int i = 1; i <= ListBox3.Items.Count-1; i++)
{
    com = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + Label6.Text + " ADD " + ListBox3.Items[i].Text.Trim() + " nvarchar(5)", con);
    con.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

I am further displaying this table using `GridView`. Like:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + Label6.Text + "", con);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
GridView2.DataSource = dt;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

The asp code for GridView is :

```
<Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
</Columns>
```

Hence, I want the first column to be readonly. 
I want to edit the `GridView` and update the customer(referring to Label6.Text) table in the database. Note: I want the GridView to accept only integers.

The image of my database table and the Gridview is shown in the following link. Kindly help. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You need to make sure you set `Label6.Text = Label6.Text + "(blah NVARCHAR(5)); DROP DATABASE; --"` first. Then read up on SQL injection.

Comment: Check [SQL Injections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To accept only numeric input, you could use a jQuery plugin. Some possibilities are presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery).

```
com = new SqlCommand("ALTER TABLE " + Label6.Text + " ADD " + ListBox3.Items[i].Text.Trim() + " nvarchar(5)", con);
```

This approach makes you vulnerable to [SQL-injection](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). Your entire application is pretty brittle by building the SQL statements like that.

To update the database, you could work in a similar way as how you created/selected from the table.

Comment: I want to update `GridView` values in the database table. I have attached an image which shows wat I want. The asp html code for the `GridView` is what I am look for and corresponding update method. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should **rethink** your approach and *change all your SQL statements* to make use of SQL Parameters. Right now your code is **extremely vulnerable to SQL-Injection**! There are plenty of examples here on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sqlparameter) or just have a look at [MSDN](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCcQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx&ei=QrBAUIO5FsTj4QTIlYCIAg&usg=AFQjCNFjjUvDUBPCM68mgin6KN-IXTnBxA&sig2=UjBDu3eU4Q46CywjyZCyAA).

Furthermore I don't think it is a good decision to let the user create a table and data on the fly imo. Anyway - if you really want to implement this on this way you might add columns dynamically

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    DataColumn dc = dt.Columns[i];
    BoundField bf = new BoundField();
    bf.ReadOnly = i == 0;  // will take care of setting controls to readonly in column 0
    bf.DataField = dc.ColumnName;
    GridView1.Columns.Add(bf);
}
```

Unfortunatelly adding a column which allows numbers only is not quite easy. In this case it would be necessary to create a templateField on the fly and add it to columns. Have a look at [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13462/How-to-create-template-columns-dynamically-in-a-gr) for that.

**EDIT**

If you try to **dynamically add Values** to a table, you should make **use** of **SQL Parameters**. (e.g `INSERT INTO tblXYZ (abc, def) values (@valueForABC, @valueForDEF)`     )

Unfortunatelly there is right now **no possibility** to use SQL Parameters **to parametherize tableNames** or **columNames**. So try to

> ...restricting the characters to A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '.', '_' and ' ' - and
>   then use whatever the appropriate bracketing is for the database (e.g.
>   [] for SQL Server, I believe) to wrap round the whole thing.

Shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372033/parametise-table-name-in-net-sql) of Jon Skeet.

Comment: Could you kindly guide me as to how can I modify my code so that it is invulnerable by modifying my code. First experience in this languages. Please oblige.

Comment: rewrote answer as of given detail