# error updating row in postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE A(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    date timestamp without time zone,
    type text,
    sub_type text,
    filename text,
    filepath text,
    filesize integer,
);
```

I have an update routine:

```
$Query = "UPDATE A SET type=\"" . $strType . "\" where id=" . intval($ID);
```

Problem:

When $strType is a string, like "lettuce" I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "lettuce" does not exist
```

When it is an int, no error.

Ideas?

more background:

- the insert code adds filename,filepath, both text types successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SQL, double-quotes are identifier delimiters.  Your UPDATE statement is trying to set the `type` column to the value of the `"lettuce"` column, which is an error if there is no column named lettuce.

You want to use single-quotes to delimit a string literal in SQL:

```
$Query = "UPDATE A SET type='" . $strType . "' where id=" . intval($ID);
```

See also "[Do different databases use different name quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote/214344#214344)"

Answer (score 3):

Your coding is open to SQL injection.  Use placeholders (probably unquoted question marks) and pass the value separately.  That avoids the problems at [XKCD](http://xkcd.org/327).

Bill has the answer to your immediate problem about column names vs strings.