# mysql trigger, text between OLD and NEW

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hello I have a problem with mysql trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_forum_admin 
    after UPDATE ON sb_admins
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    INSERT INTO `mysql_db`.`trigger_log` (`dato`, `trigger`, `status`) VALUES (NOW(), 'update_forum_admin', OLD.user+"="+NEW.user);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The problem is about:

```
OLD.user+"="+NEW.user
```

The result of this is just 0, but I wanna have it to show the Old user name plus "=" plus the new user name.

But what statement do I need for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `+` as a string-concatenation operator, but this is non-standard syntax used by Microsoft not by MySQL nor in the ANSI SQL standard.

MySQL uses a function [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). For example:

```
INSERT INTO `mysql_db`.`trigger_log` (`dato`, `trigger`, `status`) 
  VALUES (NOW(), 'update_forum_admin', CONCAT(OLD.user, '=', NEW.user));
```

ANSI SQL (and most other SQL databases) uses the double-pipe as a string concatentation operator:

```
INSERT INTO `mysql_db`.`trigger_log` (`dato`, `trigger`, `status`) 
  VALUES (NOW(), 'update_forum_admin', OLD.user || '=' || NEW.user);
```

But don't try this in MySQL unless you set the [SQL mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html) to `ANSI` or `PIPES_AS_CONCAT`. By default, `||` in MySQL is a synonym for a logical `OR`.

PS: [You should use single-quotes for string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote/214344#214344).

Answer (score 0):

You want to [concatenate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) those values into a string:

```
CONCAT(OLD.user, "=", NEW.user)
```