# Replace Single Quote by Double Quote in SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone guide me how to replace single Quote by Double Quote in SQL Server....
I am trying to Search Data (eg: Don't) from SSRS.

It is trowing an error....(Unclosed Quotation mark)

```
 set  @projectDescription = replace (@projectDescription, '''', '')
 print  @projectDescription....
```

Can u pls tell int this scenario...

Comment: I dont see any function for character replace in SSRS Searching Parameter. From .NET web application i did it by replacing single quote by double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

i Think below code will work fine..

```
    set  @projectDescription = replace (@projectDescription, '''', '''''')
    print  @projectDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

Just double the single quotes, e.g.

```
select * from sometable where searchCol like 'don''t';
```

Using double quotes is not the answer - they are being deprecated, as ANSI uses Double quotes for identifiers, not string literals. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/214344/314291)

Comment: Pls see my Updated Question with scenario...Can u pls guide that scenario?

Comment: I would suggest that you try and parameterise the sql, or better still, create a stored procedure (`select * from sometable where searchcol like '%'+@mySearchPhrase+'%';`) - this way let the driver do all the hard work escaping for you.