# mysql select from table where column name equals

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table

```
amps | 120-240 | 120-208 | 277-480
__________________________________

10   |  $99.00  | $149.00 | $344.00

20   | $199.00 | $298.00 | $688
```

I want a query something like this but I can't get it to work ...

```
select * from `table` where amps like '10' and column_name like '120-208';
```

or

```
select * from `table` where amps like '20' and column_name like '277-480';
```

Please Help!  Maybe I am overlooking an easier way to set this up?

Thanks!

Comment: You really like `LIKE` but I don't think you know what it does.

Comment: 1. Normalize your data. You are overlooking an easier way to set this up.

Answer (score 4):

Just like this?

```
SELECT `120-208` FROM table WHERE amps = '10'
```

Comment: If the numeric values are really column names, it should be `SELECT \`120-208\` FROM`

Comment: `[...]` is Sybase notation. `\`...\`` is MySQL.

Comment: That throws me an error ... I just need to get the $ cost for amps where the column name equals one of those voltages.

Comment: You are both correct ... I used Marc's statement with tadman's syntax and it works perfectly! Thanks

Comment: No worries. Apologies, I'm from a TSQL background, not MySQL so my mistake on the square-bracket syntax. Glad it helped though. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: FYI, both MySQL and Microsoft/Sybase use non-standard delimiters. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/214344/20860