# Why is the MySQL query giving a syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax-error

I have the following query which I am running in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE BookingGuide (
    'ID_INT' INTEGER NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'NAME' VARCHAR(60),
    'SPECIALTY' VARCHAR(60)
    ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID_INT' INTEGER NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
     'NAME' VARCHAR(60),
 ' at line 2
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: This might be helpful for you: [Do different databases use different name quote?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote/214344#214344)

Comment: A simple beginner's tutorial might be a good place to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes around your column identifiers. Use ticks or nothing at all.

```
CREATE TABLE BookingGuide (
    ID_INT INTEGER NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(60),
    SPECIALTY VARCHAR(60)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE BookingGuide (
    `ID_INT` INTEGER NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NAME` VARCHAR(60),
    `SPECIALTY` VARCHAR(60)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Comment: I am used to SQL programming and wasn't aware of the ` instead of the '. Thanks.

Comment: @SiKni8 yes in mysql single quotes are not supported for col names , if you wish you can use backtick else leave it without anything, but beware mysql has set of reserved keywords and if you by any chance use them then you have to backtick them else you will get error.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I am guessing it's the same in SQL as well but thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
     CREATE TABLE BookingGuide (
     ID_INT INTEGER NOT NULL primary key AUTO_INCREMENT,
     NAME VARCHAR(60),
     SPECIALTY VARCHAR(60)
     ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

instead of single quote you need backticks.

Comment: I am used to SQL programming and wasn't aware of the ` instead of the '. Thanks.