# SQL Error Whilst Creating New User

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new user and grant permissions for all tables in my db on `mySQL`.

I'm using this command:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mailserver.* TO `mailuser`@`127.0.0.1` IDENTIFIED BY `mailuserpass`;
```

However for some reason I'm receiving this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '`wefewwehappyfew`' at line 1

I've done some googling and I can't seem to work out what's going wrong here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try to remove `  character..and around your password use `'pass'`

Comment: That worked, thankyou! No idea why the website I was copying from used ` ` ` rather than `'` well spotted!

Comment: that depends on your database quotes --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote

Comment: Ahh, well thanks for resolving the issue.

Comment: you are welcome :)