# Convert an MySQL script to Presto involving DATE_FORMAT

Tags: mysql, date-format, presto, trino

I'm trying to convert this MySQL line:

```sql
if(DATE_FORMAT(y.first_endperiod,"%Y-%m-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(x.end_period,"%Y-%m-%d"), 1, 0) = 1
```

to PrestoDB. I have tried using `date_format`, `date_parse`, and `to_char`, and all of them return the following error:

`An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 40:41: Column '%y-%m-%d' cannot be resolved`.

I'm using Athena for querying data from S3 bucket. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What about `if cast(date_parse(y.first_endperiod, '%Y-%m-%d') as date) = cast(date_parse(x.end_period, '%Y-%m-%d') as date)` ?

Comment: Nevermind, already solved this. I changed the double apostrophe to single apostrophe and all good.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing date/time by the date portion, so you should just be able to do this:

```
CAST(y.first_endperiod AS date) = CAST(x.end_period AS date)
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, the double-quotes are used to delimit identifiers, e.g. column names. So your SQL query above is interpreted as if you had a column named `%Y-%m-%d`. This is unlikely, but technically it'd be a legal identifier in SQL.

You're probably accustomed to MySQL, in which by default double-quotes are used the same as single-quotes, to delimit a string literal. This is a non-standard feature of MySQL.

Switch to single-quotes around your string literals and it should fix your problem:

```
if(DATE_FORMAT(y.first_endperiod,'%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(x.end_period,'%Y-%m-%d'), 1, 0) = 1
```

See also [Do different databases use different name quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214309/do-different-databases-use-different-name-quote/214344#214344)